# how to set up Drive SDK so you dont need a success token each time you run .py

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

At the moment i am needing to get a "success code" each time i want to run my .py app. to access my googdrive files which is a pain.

I saw Ali Afshars great vid on https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters where he uses:
`from auth import http` to streamline this process.

Not sure what this function should contain... Can you point me in the right direction, so that i can set up my .py to do this automatically ...or at least only once.

many thanks

Dav-o

---

**EDIT** relevant current snip of code follows:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
import httplib2
import pprint
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import *
from apiclient import errors

CLIENT_ID = "864350......ps.googleusercontent.com"
CLIENT_SECRET = "sw0yb.....-zR6XWzEgM"
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' 
REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oo...ooo' # Redirect URI for installed apps

flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)
authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
print 'Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url
code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)

http = httplib2.Http() 
http = credentials.authorize(http)

drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What he probably does in `auth` is:

```
import httplib2
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2Credentials

http = httplib2.Http()
credentials = OAuth2Credentials(access_token, client_id, client_secret, refresh_token, None, '', '')
credentials.authorize(http)
```

You can wrap this code in a module/method and use the authenticate your requests. For multiple user scenarios, preserve access and refresh tokens (most likely in a db) and init credentials object with the stored tokens.

Comment: Thanks Burcu. this is a great start. how do i get an 'access_token'. is this the same as the success code that i copy and paste in to the application? Also what is 'refresh_token' too. I have edited the question to show the current code.  Thanks!

Comment: credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code) contains an access token. It's not code you copy and paste. Take a look at https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ to understand the flow.

Comment: Burcu = awesome. I had no idea there was an OAuth 2.0 PLayground! I think i've read LOTS of the documentation, never saw a reference to it at all.  I will look at this :) cheers!

Comment: If you haven't seen, please also take a look at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2 and https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer. Once you exchange code and retrieve tokens, persist them on session or another storage. Access tokens are being expired but you can retrieve another  with a refresh token.

Comment: Thanks Burcu. Very helpful and very clearly explained! Appreciated